# Avoiding OFFSET, how the WHERE paging should look like?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I was reading http://domasmituzas.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/mysqluc2008-mysql-web.pdf 
and found that "Good paging practice" is with WHERE and not OFFSET, LIMIT

Any code examples, explanation how to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no sql guru. But as far as I know, `WHERE` clause indicates what row to be selected on that particular `TABLE`. This is performed first before the `LIMIT` clause.

The `LIMIT` clause limits the number of rows to be returned by the `SELECT` statement. So this clause is performed after the `WHERE` clause, which concludes that `WHERE` is faster than `LIMIT`.

Still the `WHERE` clause's [PERFORMANCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html) depends on how you form your conditions.

Here's what I use for paging:

```
SELECT *
    FROM table T
    WHERE T.Id > 100
    LIMIT 100;
```

Instead of using `LIMIT`/`OFFSET`.

```
SELECT *
    FROM table T
    LIMIT 100, 100;
```

You can clearly see the advantage for large tables.

Answer (score 1):

[A better presentation](http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/ppc2009/PPC2009_mysql_pagination.pdf) is available which has the explanation and examples of how to implement pagination without using OFFSET.

**Quotes:**

> Larger OFFSET is going to increase active data set, MySQL has to bring
>   data in memory that is never returned to caller.

An alternative solution is to store the last seen id.
For next page, http://domain.com/forum?page=2&last_seen=100&dir=next, the query is:

```
SELECT ... WHERE id < 100 /* last_seen */ BY id ORDER BY DESC LIMIT $page_size
```

For previous page: http://domain.com/forum?page=1&last_seen=98&dir=prev:

```
SELECT ... WHERE id > 98 /* last_seen */ ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $page_size
```